# Eclipse empty all file contents from Android project, how to fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a existing Android project which was worked (compile and execute) correctly. I was done with this project, so I remove this from eclipse project explorer. I saved a backup copy of this project. After few days later I import it. I found eclipse empties all *.java and *.xml files. As I have backup I tried to import this project couple of times. It happens all the time.

I tired to check the same project with other pc. It worked fine. So I am sure there is no problem with project configuration. It must be some thing wrong with eclipse.

Actually it happened earlier with some other project. I just ignored last time.

How to fix it?

Comment: extract this project in some folder, e.g `C:\temp\project` and then import it into your workspace. Maybe you import project which is already in workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy your android project in another folder as another copy and open the old project in eclipse if it is showing all file empty.! then go to the folder where your project exist and again replace all the content by copy-pasting from newly copied project and go to eclipse and refresh on the project.